# Captioning a figure with multiple subfigures all at once

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions, subfloats

I want to create a figure with subfigures, and then reference them from the caption of the main figure:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}
        A figure
        \caption{}
        \label{a}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~
    \begin{subfigure}
        B figure
        \caption{}
        \label{b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{ \ref{a}) about figure A, \ref{b}) about figure B }
\end{figure}
```

This doesn't work as written, how do I do something similar?

Comment: The environment `subfigure` is provided by the package `subfigure` which is obsolete. You should use `subcation` instead. However if I use your code snippet it works well.

Comment: Marco meant `subcaption`.

Comment: weirdly enough, I'm using the package `subcaption`... which also provides the `subfigure` environment

Comment: @AndrewSpott: The environment `subfigure` of `subcaption` has an mandatory argument.

Comment: @AndrewSpott such misunderstandings would not occur if your question contained a complete document, which is why we always ask for examples to start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` showing all packages used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `subfigure` provides the environment `subfigure`. I guess you are using it. This package is obsolete and you should use the package `subfig` or `subcaption` (recommended) (provides nearly the same environment).

However the following example works well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}
        A figure
        \caption{}
        \label{a}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~
    \begin{subfigure}
        B figure
        \caption{}
        \label{b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{ \ref{a}) about figure A, \ref{b}) about figure B }
    \label{fig:TheWholeFigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Using `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
        A figure
        \caption{}
        \label{a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
        B figure
        \caption{}
        \label{b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{ \ref{a}) about figure A, \ref{b}) about figure B }
    \label{fig:TheWholeFigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to reference the whole image, use `\ref{fig:TheWholeFigure}`.